# Solving mixing 3 parts to get desire percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have a desire percentage of mixing 3 elements to achieve a whole product. 
desired percentage of elements are : 
40% of X , 40% of Y , 20% of Z

But we have a product currently which is include of  :
5% of X ,  60% of Y , 35% of Z

Question : what percentage mix of the elements X, Y and Z we should use AND combine with the current product, to achieve the desired product ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on the problem, Pari?

Answer (score 0):

Let the hypothetical percentage mix of $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be $(p,q,r)$. We have the fraction $t$ of this mix and the rest $(1-t)$ of the $(5,60,35)$ mix and we get $(40,40,20)$. Therefore we have
$$t(p,q,r)+ (1-t) (5,60,35)= (40,40,20)$$
so 
$$(p,q,r) = (5,60,35)+\frac{1}{t} ((40,40,20) - (5,60,35)) = 
(5,60,35) + \frac{1}{t} (35, -20, -15)$$
Now the percentages $(p,q,r)$ need to be $\ge 0$ so we have conditions
$$q = 60 -20/t \ge 0 \\
r = 35 - 15/t \ge 0 $$
that is $t \ge 20/60 = 1/3$ and $t \ge 15/35 = 3/7$, and so $[3/7,1]$ 
is the allowed interval for $t$.

In the particular case $t = 3/7$ we have
$$(p,q,r) = (5,60,35)+ 7/3 (35, -20, -15) = (86.66\ldots, 13.33\ldots, 0)$$
Recipe: take $3$ parts of $(86.66\ldots, 13.33\ldots, 0)$ mixture and $4$ parts of $(5,60,35)$ mixture to get $(40,40,20)$ mixture

Comment: Not leaving OP with much to do.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: might  be a hand sanitizer recipe... so this will help speed things up a bit    :-)